# Two disjoint convex sets that cannot be separated in a Hilbert space by a linear functional.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

[image]

I think I figured it out. The proof the set $\Omega$ is convex is very easy. Now the next part, let $x^* \in H$ then $x^*=\Sigma(x^*,e_k)e_k$ and so $(x^*,x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}(\sum_{0}^{n}(x^*,e_k)e_k,\sum_{0}^{m}c_ke_k)$ Now we can assume $n>m$ and make use of linearity and orthonormality of $e_k$ to conclude that $(x^*,x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}(\sum_{0}^{n}(x^*,e_k)e_k,\sum_{0}^{m}c_ke_k)=\sum_{0}^{m}(x^*,e_k)c_i$ Now we know this sum is not $0$ for any choice of $m$ and $c_i$ as the would imply $x^*=0$ thus we have at least one is non zero. Thus we can use that non-zero part, to get any real number (it is a little more nuanced but i am sure i got this part right).

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

There are notational incosistencies in your argument and the logic itslef is not clear. Where did you use the fact that last coffecient is non-zero?

Here is  proof: Suppose $x^{*}(e_k) \neq 0$. If $x^{*}(e_k) > 0$ then $x^{*} (-ne_k+e_{k+1})\to -\infty$    and $x^{*} (ne_k+e_{k+1})\to \infty$. Now $x^{*}(\Omega)$  is a convex set in $\mathbb R$ so it is an interval. Hence it contains all real numbers. Similar argument holds when $x^{*}(e_k) <0$.